# Why is VS Code putting "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -e" in front of my tasks and how do I stop it?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I have this build task:

```
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "C:\\Users\\m\\Desktop\\qmk\\QMK_MSYS\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe -l -i -c 'qmk compile -kb handwired/dactyl_manuform/5x6 -km mdactyl'",
    },
```

I have also tried it with

```
        "args": ["-l", "-i", "-c", "'qmk compile -kb handwired/dactyl_manuform/5x6 -km mdactyl'"]
```

I need to use precisely the bash.exe I have specified there, not one from WSL, but when I run this task, I get this output:

```
 *  Executing task: C:\Users\m\Desktop\qmk\QMK_MSYS\usr\bin\bash.exe 'qmk compile -kb handwired/dactyl_manuform/5x6 -km mdactyl' 


 *  The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -e C:\Users\m\Desktop\qmk\QMK_MSYS\usr\bin\bash.exe 'qmk compile -kb handwired/dactyl_manuform/5x6 -km mdactyl'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

The executing task line looks correct, but the terminal process line doesn't. Somehow, wsl.exe got involved.

I'm not really sure that this is what's causing my exit code 1, but it's the first place to look. So what's going on?

Comment: Have you defined the default shell to be the bash shell by chance within VS Code?

Comment: aha, yes. changing that to cmd fixed it. now I'm trying to find a way to leave my default shell as bash and configure the build task instead

Comment: Windows 10 or Windows 11?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: It’s not possible to set WSL bash terminal to default she’ll handler on Windows 10.